# android resource string %

Tags: android, string, resources

now I encounter a doubt about % in android string resource. The question as follow:

If I want to use % symbol in other language, such as in chinese. I must add resource string formatted="false" in /values-zh-rCN/strings.xml.

Yes, the string tag must have ther formatted attribute.

However, it could not add this formatted attribute in /values/strings.xml  in english language. it compile successfully, and work well.

Why?

I can't find any answer in android developer website.

ps: how i write Angle brackets in stackoverflow editor. I'm a freshman.

Java code:

```
autoDownloadLayout.findViewById(R.id.setItemContent)).setText(R.string.setting_auto_update_title_1_subtitle);
```

/values/strings.xml :

```
<string name="setting_auto_update_title_1_subtitle">Automatically download updates when connected to Wi-Fi, when the battery level is greater than 30% and CPU usage is less than 50%</string>
```

/values-zh-rCN/strings.xml :

```
<string formatted="false" name="setting_auto_update_title_1_subtitle">"仅在 WLAN 网络，手机电量高于 30% 且 CPU 占用率低于 50% 时，预先下载游戏更新包"</string>
```

Comment: Please post the xml (and the Java code) that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: If you have in your properties file:

```<string name="age_message">My age is %s</string>```

you can use something like this:

```String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.age_message), "29")```. The result will be ```My age is 29```

Comment: You can write angle brackets in-line by surrounding them with accent grave characters (`\``). You can write blocks of code by indenting at least four spaces.

Comment: @AlbertoAnderickJr - or, more concisely, `getResources().getString(R.string.age_message, "29")`, which will do the formatting when retrieving the string.

Comment: @TedHopp   I have post my code and xml.  and thank you for telling me  edit skills. 3Q

Comment: Okay, that helps. When you say that you "must add" the `formatted` attribute, is that to deal with a lint error? Or is this an issue with run-time behavior? (If a lint error is preventing you from running the code, you can get past that by setting lint options to ignore the error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Android Lint has different ideas when checking translated strings as compared to default strings. There's an open issue ([Issue 74959](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74959)) about this (although it's not exactly your problem). It would seem that technically you should be adding `formatted="false"` to the strings in `/values` as well as to those in `/values-zh-rCN`.

Alternatively, you could encode all literal percent signs as `&#37;` (or `&#x25;`). That might be the simplest (and least risky) approach.